# What is the role of acid in keto enol tautomerism

Tags: organic-chemistry, tautomer

I have heard about an acid acting as a catalyst in keto enol tatutomerism.I have yet to understand the mechanism of the reaction though.pictorial depictions are welcome.

Comment: Please see the site's [homework policy](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange). You should amend your post to include what work you've done towards an answer.

Comment: ill do it next time onwards.I am new to this site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In acid-catalysed keto-enol tautomerism, a lone pair of electrons is removed from the oxygen of carbonyl group by the acid.
 [image]

If enol is the starting compound, [markovnikov's](http://www.organic-chemistry.org/namedreactions/markovnikovs-rule.shtm) addition of $\ce{H+}$ occurs.[image]